# Django - prefetch_related for specific situation doesn't work

Tags: python, sql, django, orm, django-orm

I have a three models: `Trip`, `City` and `GoogleApiCityCache`.

If I want to know name of the city, I use `@property` on `City` object which tries to get `GoogleApiCityCache` for current language.

I want to reduce a number of queries in my template:

```
{% for trip in trips %}
    {{ trip.city.formatted_address }}
{% endfor %}
```

Now, it performs new db query to find `GoogleApiCityCache` in each iteration. I want to prefetch these caches.

So property `formatted_address` has to find a `GoogleApiCityCache` and get `formatted_address` from this object.

Tried to use `prefetch_related` but it doesn't help.

```
def profile(request, slug):
    owner = User.objects.filter(userprofile__slug=slug).prefetch_related('trips__city__city_caches').first()
    trips = Trip.objects.filter(user=owner).select_related('city').prefetch_related('city__city_caches')
    return render(request, 'profiles/profile/profile.html', {'owner': owner,'trips':trips})
```

My models:

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='trips')
    city = models.ForeignKey('locations.City', related_name='trips')
    date_from = models.DateField()
    date_to = models.DateField()
    detail = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    # participants = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', related_name='participating_on_trips', blank=True)
    objects = TripManager()

class City(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_cache_by_lang(self, lang=None, force_refresh=False):
        if not lang:
            lang = get_language() or 'en'
        cache, requested = GoogleApiCityCache.objects.get_or_request(city=self, lang=lang)
        return cache

    @property
    def formatted_address(self):
        return self.get_cache_by_lang().formatted_address

class GoogleApiCityCacheManager(models.Manager):
    def _request_create(self, city, lang):
        """ Create cache (wasn't found) """
        ....
        return cache

    def get_or_request(self, city, lang):
        created = False
        try:
            cache = GoogleApiCityCache.objects.get(city=city, language_code=lang)
        except GoogleApiCityCache.DoesNotExist:
            cache = self._request_create(city, lang)
            created = True
        return cache,created

class GoogleApiCityCache(models.Model):
    language_code = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    api_json_response = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey('locations.City', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='city_caches')
    objects = GoogleApiCityCacheManager()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('city', 'language_code')


    @property
    def formatted_address(self):
        try:
            return self.api_json_response['result']['formatted_address']
        except:
            return None
```

As you can see, `GoogleApiCityCache` for `city` and `language_code` can be none. In this case, the Google Api is requested, created a new `GoogleApiCityCache` object and returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `prefetch_related('trips__city__city_caches')`, you are prefetching the `city_caches`. That means that the following loop will not cause any extra queries.

```
for cache in city.city_caches.all()
    print(cache)
```

However, in your code `formatted_address` calls `get_cache_by_lang` which calls `get_or_request` which calls `GoogleApiCityCache.objects.get()`, which will cause extra queries.

In order to take advantage of `prefetch_related`, you need to rewrite `get_cache_by_lang` so that it loops through `self.city_caches.all()` to find the correct object.